# NDlib Independent Cascade initialisation is giving me an error

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using NDlib to try and model an Independent Cascade diffusion process over a graph. I am trying to set some initial seed nodes using `config.add_model_parameter('Infected', {0, 10, 100})` (the rest of my code to this point is the same as the tutorial example found [here](https://ndlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/models/epidemics/IndependentCascades.html)) but I get the error `UserWarning: Initial infection missing: a random sample of 5% of graph nodes will be set as infected warnings.warn('Initial infection missing: a random sample of 5% of graph nodes will be set as infected')` when I then run the line `model.set_initial_status(config)`. I am not sure how this is happening as in the documentation linked it says the initial infection status can be defined via two options, the first option is what is used in the tutorial and the second is what I am trying to specify instead. Does anyone know why it is not seeming to recognise my initial seed nodes?

The full code I am using is this:

```
g = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.05, seed=1)
model = ep.IndependentCascadesModel(g)

config = mc.Configuration()
# config.add_model_parameter('fraction_infected', 0)
config.add_model_parameter('Infected', {0, 10, 100})
threshold = 0.01
for e in g.edges():
    config.add_edge_configuration("threshold", e, threshold)
model.set_initial_status(config)  # this line triggers the warning
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ndlib, you should be using `add_model_initial_configuration` instead of `add_model_parameter`, please look at this example: https://ndlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/mconf/Mconf.html#status-configuration

Comment: Glad it was helpful! If it solved your question, please accept the answer :)

Comment: I will, it said I had to wait 6 minutes! however, I now have a new error that `'IndependentCascadesModel' object has no attribute 'add_model_initial_configuration'` -- I think I may be using it wrong, give me time to check this out.

Comment: Oh... you should use `add_model_initial_configuration` on the `ModelConfig` object, not on the `IndependentCascadeModel` object

Comment: yes, I just realised that! it has been a long day.... thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
g = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.05, seed=1)
seed_set = set(['0', '10', '100'])
model = ep.IndependentCascadesModel(g)

config = mc.Configuration()
config.add_model_initial_configuration("Infected", seed_set)

threshold = 0.01
for e in g.edges():
    config.add_edge_configuration("threshold", e, threshold)
model.set_initial_status(config)
```